# Git config values clash

Tags: windows, ssl, github, mingw32, git-lfs

I ran into big git configuration problem on my windows laptop. I downloaded Git for Desktop since I wasn't able to install git lfs to my cygwin git. I then removed the git from cygwin. I have a GitHub project which is using git-lfs for storing 
large files. When I clone the project and it starts downloading files from the remote server it says:

```
WARNING: These git config values clash:
git config "http.sslcainfo" = "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
git config "http.sslcainfo" = "/ssl/certs/ca-bundle-ghfw.crt"
```

Neither of those file locations exist on my computer. When I use *git config --list* I can see both values for http.sslcainfo. But the mingw one is not listed in with any of the *git config --system --list, git config --global --list or git config --local --list*. So I can't locate the file where
configuration is. I assume the Git for Desktop wants to use the /ssl/certs/ location since it sets it to git config --system when it is installed. I also have installed mingw on my computer but I couldn't find .gitconfig file inside it. Also I don't know why git would even look from there or where the configurations might be saved. I'm able to clone repository which doesn't use git-lfs. So is there any way to remove the *http.sslcainfo = "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt"* configuration? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, i have to tell you that im not sure if i can help you. However, i want to share my information with you.... maybe it helps. I am tying out git-lfs for some big repos at the moment. I am using the bitbucket test server. Atleast on bitbucket, they say that files from git lfs are downloaded via HTTPS and need an ssl cert.

I hope that this helps you a bit. If you got more questions about this, feel free to ask.

Frossy